# When entering Australia with an eVisitor visa, do I need a return ticket?

Tags: visas, tickets, australia

I'm about to go to Australia with an [eVisitor (subclass 651) visa](http://www.immi.gov.au/Visas/Pages/651.aspx). This is a tourist visa available for people with a passport from a European country.

I haven't found any mention on the Australia Immigration site about whether I need a return ticket or not.

Comment: In my experience, buying the same ticket in Australia rather than the UK, for example, is an awful lot more expensive, so for purely financial reasons I'd enter with a return ticket. And there is the risk that they are not convinced that you intend to leave the country.

Comment: I understand your point, but I'm traveling one country at a time and I don't intend to return to the country I'll come from. I'm also thinking to leave by sail boat, hence I would prefer not to buy a return ticket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Immigration Advice & Rights Centre has a pdf document on Visitor Visas, including the 651](http://www.iarc.asn.au/LiteratureRetrieve.aspx?ID=40031).

Essentially, you have to be able to prove to the immigration officer that you have the intent to return home. ONE of the means of doing so includes having a purchased return ticket, showing that you're leaving the country on day x.

Most countries have this requirement for tourist visas, and for example, in America, it's very common among travellers to purchase a cheap bus ticket from Seattle to Vancouver as 'evidence' that they're leaving.  Then when they've worked out where they're actually going, they buy a ticket to there, and forfeit the bus ticket.

Leaving by sail boat would be harder to prove, and indeed what might be easier is to produce an 'onward' ticket - for example, a cheap flight to New Zealand, or Singapore or something.  Ideally you'd purchase a refundable or adjustable ticket, so that you can change it or get a refund when/if you go by boat instead.

I recommend having a read of that pdf, it gives you several of the other options on what would be 'evidence' of intent to return, including a job, lease agreement or more.